# What does it mean to "join" a thread?

Tags: c

For my class I'm supposed to find out what's wrong with a piece of code, and the part I'm having trouble deciphering is

```
// joining a thread blocks until that thread finishes
a.join();
b.join();
```

Is joining a thread the same as locking a thread?  Because I think the point of this assignment is you're not supposed to leave threads unlocked.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is how one thread waits for the completion of another thread!

A nice use case of `join` is - say for example the `main()` function/thread  creates a thread and doesn't wait ( using `join` ) for the created thread to complete and simply exits, then the newly created thread will also stop!

Here is a [nice explanation](http://cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/FUNDAMENTALS/thread-management.html) of Thread Management in general and Thread Join in particular! And here are some [code snippets](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=15716) that show you some use cases of `join` and what happens when you don't use it!

Answer (score 13):

Think of starting a thread as "forking" your process into two distinct threads of execution. Then, join is the reverse -- it's where these two separate threads join together (and only the parent continues from there).

Answer (score 9):

To join a thread means to wait until that thread is live. When the thread exits, the thread calling `join()` will continue executing. Thus, in the above example, the thread (presumably main thread) that is calling `a.join()` and `b.join()` will wait until both threads `a` and `b` (in that order) finish their job and then continue executing the code that is after `b.join()`.

Answer (score 7):

The comment says it all, really. Joining a thread means to wait for it to complete. That is, block the current thread until another completes.

Answer (score 6):

1. join() waits on a thread to complete it's execution.
2. You need to either detach() a thread or join() a thread for managing it.
3. join() also, cleans up the thread occupied resources. You will find join() called in the  destructor of an RAII class because of the same reason.