# Why isn't joining threads enough to fix data inconsistencies issues when having concurrent threads?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Joining two threads means one will complete after the other thread complete its tasks; therefore, we achieve atomicity with join(). So, why isn't that enough? In which case should we use join()?

Comment: Why isn't that enough for what?

Comment: Enough to avoid race conditions, judging by the title. I agree the question itself is not totally clear though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why join?** Joining is useful when a main thread wants to launch a bunch of parallel task threads to speed up some work. The main thread "joins" with the task threads (i.e. it waits for them to complete their tasks and terminate). That way it can move forward knowing that the tasks have been completed.

For example, a portal home page might need to load a bunch of widgets displaying data from various sources. One approach to implementing this is to have the request processing thread launch parallel task threads to grab the data. That way the user doesn't have to wait longer than the slowest task thread, roughly, instead of waiting for all data to load serially. The request processing thread would join with those threads to ensure that all the widgets have the data they need before displaying the home page.

**Regarding data inconsistency.** If the task threads are all accessing shared data, there has to be some way to ensure that they don't mosh over each other. The fact that some other thread is waiting for the task threads to complete doesn't prevent that moshing. (Mosh = [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)).

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is useful to achieve tasks parallelly. And in most of the cases they act on the same data. In such a case, there is always the danger of inconsistent data. A good example is,

```
Main Thread creates two threads A and B
and waits for them to execute and JOIN
Balance=1000;
Thread A wants to withdraw 300 and Thread B wants to deposit 450
Thread A reads Balance 1000
Context Switch
Thread B reads Balance 1000
Thread B adds 450 to value read.Hence, 1000+450=1450
Write back to Balance;
Balance=1450;
Context Switch
Thread A deducts 300 from value read.Hence, 1000-300=700
Write back to Balance.
Balance=700
Both threads now join the main Thread.
Main thread does further processing.
```

In this case, even though there was a `join`  you can see how data is inconsistent.
There is a need for mutual exclusion.

`Join` on the other hand is used to wait for threads rather, possibly when the main thread wants to do further work only when the other threads have finished their jobs.

If that is not the case, you can detach the spawned threads. Then there is no need for the main thread to wait for the threads to finish execution. EVEN then, the need for mutual exclusion arises.

Read this, [What does it mean to join a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366264/what-does-it-mean-to-join-a-thread)?

I don't have a general link to explain but I guess the explanation is quite applicable for all threads (Not just pthreads).

From [OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html)

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling
>   thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread
>   has already terminated

Comment: One good link, http://cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/FUNDAMENTALS/thread-management.html

Answer (score 0):

Atomicity doesn't mean that threads should finish in particular order.
It implies the operations should be done atomically and 2 threads should not interfere in each others tasks, so that state remians consistent. And this is achieved by using `synchronized` block `AtomicIntegers` etc..

Comment: Note that atomicity is different than both isolation and consistency. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID. Atomicity is the "all-or-nothing" property: either the whole task completes or none of it does.